Short story with people hired because Murphy's Law is stronger for them
I remember reading this short story in the past 5 years, probably in a back issue of Analog.
A number of people for whom Murphy's Law seemed especially effective were hired to live in an underground bunker/habitat and use new products so that bugs could be found more quickly. Each individual had a rating to show how frequently and badly things would go wrong for them, and these effects would "stack" with multiple people nearby each other.
In one incident, a bug turned out to be a feature when a man ran naked through a black material being used to separate standard pressure from vacuum. The material stuck to his body (and eyes, blinding him temporarily), forming a flexible, reusable space suit. When he passed through the barrier again, the material on his body rejoined it, coming off cleanly.

Were they "abnotechnological" by any chance? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/242847/tracking-down-a-short-story-with-the-term-abnotechia-or-abtechnological

@ClaraDíazSanchez That sounds about right. I'll search through that issue of Analog when I get home to confirm.

Seems like the reverse of puppeteers from Larry Niven’s Known Space intentionally breeding “lucky” humans

@ClaraDíazSanchez Exactly the story I was looking for.
